# Pixel 4a - is it possible to play music (in car) over USB?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, music-player, google-pixel-4a

Is it possible to play music from my Pixel 4a over USB in my car?

My car is a Ford Focus from 2016. If I plug in an iPhone, the car just starts to play whatever music was last listened to (or just starts playing the first track in the alphabet). This is great.

However, I'd rather use an Android phone than an iPhone, and the Pixel 4a is otherwise great, but the playing over USB feature is important to me; the sound over Bluetooth in this car is rather poor.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

I've tried some different music apps - e.g. USB Audio Player PRO - to no avail; even using the USB OTG extension that came with the phone.

`USB Preferences` are set to `File transfer/Android Auto`

I also saw this question: [2012 question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23727/can-i-get-my-cars-head-unit-to-play-audio-via-usb-from-my-galaxy-s3) from 2012 and thought (hoped) things had moved on since then.

Comment: I don't think this is so much an Android question as a question about your headunit... This required the headunit be able to read the media library and playback via USB, it's a feature of the headset (my JVC unit can do this), and a little finesse of allowing USB connections in the device... It's not really an Android thing.

Comment: Ok, so do you mean that e.g. something like this might work? https://www.amazon.com/T-Style-Replacement-2012-2018-Wireless-Touchscreen/dp/B09GVPBTS4

Comment: You should check if your version of Ford SYNC is supported by Android Auto: https://www.ford.com/support/how-tos/sync/getting-started-with-sync/which-vehicles-are-compatible-with-android-auto/ Additionally you may want to document/edit your post to include which `USB Preferences` (search in Settings) is configured/has been tested.

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang, looks like my car is juuust too old; I have SYNC with "My Ford Touch", need SYNC 3 with touch screen or newer. I'll also update the question as you suggest :)

Comment: Just another personal experience: I have been listening to music on the Honda HR-V (2017) head unit (not sure about the model) using Nexus 5 (Lineage OS 14.1, Android 7.1.2), micro-USB (somehow Bluetooth was not working), and Spotify app. The head unit doesn't support Android Auto. So, the answer to the title is highly certain "yes", but looks like the answer to the detail in the question is "depend" (as @acejavelin has explained)